# Password generator issues

Tags: javascript

My code for my assignment is supposed to prompt the user for the password length and character types. When prompted, I want the user to be able to type in up to 3 answers (i.e. "uppercase, lowercase, special") but when I run it, it only accepts one answer. Here is my code, please help:

```
var length = Number(prompt("Enter a password length between 8 and 128")),
  charType = prompt("Enter up to 3 character types: special, numeric, uppercase, lowercase."),

  password = generatePassword();
document.getElementById("display").value = password;
document.getElementById('copy-btn').addEventListener('click', copyPassword);

function generatePassword() {
  var charSets = {
    lowercase: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    uppercase: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    numeric: '0123456789',
    special: ' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
  };
  var charSet = charSets[charType.toLowerCase()] || charSets.lowercase;
  var retVal = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    retVal += charSet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length));
  }
  return retVal;
}

function copyPassword() {
  document.getElementById("display").select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  alert("Password copied to clipboard!");
}
```

Comment: What is the expected format for multiple answers? Is it a single, delimited string, eg `"lowercase, uppercase, special"` or were you wanting to prompt multiple times?

Comment: i wanted a single prompt for it.

Comment: Right, so what is the expected format of that answer? Sounds like you'll want to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) that string

Comment: "lowercase, uppercase, special" and "lowercase uppercase special" should both be accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the input on a comma and multiple spaces or just multiple spaces (using regular expressions, as suggested by [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil)) and loop over each part, concatenating all the specified char sets together.

```js
var length = Number(prompt("Enter a password length between 8 and 128")),
  charType = prompt("Enter up to 3 character types: special, numeric, uppercase, lowercase."),

  password = generatePassword();
document.getElementById("display").value = password;
document.getElementById('copy-btn').addEventListener('click', copyPassword);

function generatePassword() {
  var charSets = {
    lowercase: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    uppercase: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    numeric: '0123456789',
    special: ' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
  };
  var charSet = charType? 
    charType.split(/,\s*|\s+/).reduce((acc,curr)=>acc + charSets[curr.trim().toLowerCase()],"") 
    : charSets.lowercase;
  var retVal = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    retVal += charSet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length));
  }
  return retVal;
}

function copyPassword() {
  document.getElementById("display").select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  alert("Password copied to clipboard!");
}
```

```html
<textarea id="display"></textarea>
<button id="copy-btn">Copy<button>
```

Comment: Sounds like OP wants to split on varied delimiters. I'd go with `split(/,?\s*/)`

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: where do I put the split?

Comment: Oops, I messed up that regex. You should probably test it first. Sorry

Comment: Try `split(/,\s*|\s+/)`. Again, sorry for the bad info

Comment: @AiyaSiddig No problem.

Comment: how do I do so?